# Is there any way to delete the existing task of debezium mysql connector and replace it with new task

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am using a Debezium mysql connector, I want to replace the existing task with new task.

Comment: Do you mean *task*, or do you mean *connector*? A connector is the configuration, a task (or tasks) is how the connector's work is actually executed.

Answer (score 0):

Tasks are all configured at the worker level.

You would have to send your configuration to the `PUT <connector>/config` endpoint.